# dynamic activity

Tags: android

I have made a layout for my app which uses a lot of activities. I sent my app to my friend and in which he said my layout was all wrong he told me i need to not use as many activitys and dailogs and to make the activity dynamic. He told me to read about this and it will help me. Now as you see in the link. i have tryed my best to show what i am after.
I have been looking on the net but cant find what am after 
I get what he's saying i can sort of change view on the same activity but i cant see how i can use all this information and just use 1 activity. seem like to me the app will run slow
If anyone can show me a link to a blog, site,video etc, to show me how this is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're friend is getting at is that Data and Views shouldn't be closely tied. Based on your illustration you only need 1 activity and 1 layout. Then you can use the data stored in XML, JSON, or SQLite, etc. to add data to your ListView (and Binder). These are the basic steps:

1. The Activity and view is created in `onCreate()`.
2. Data is read from where ever it happens to be, then transformed into a structure the binder can understand. (List of HashMap for example).
3. The binder "glues" the data to the ListView to bind them together.
4. The ListView is rendered to the screen for interaction with the user.

A properly implemented binder will be able to use one ListView layout and one ListView item layout with good performance. Check out the [ListView sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). It uses a basic binder (`ArrayAdapter`), so after you fully understand this sample checkout the other binders.